# Sync contacts on Outlook 2007 with Android 2.0 via usb

Tags: usb, sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, android, contacts

My boss got a new HTC something from Verizon.

He wants to sync his Outlook contacts with the handset. He doesn't need to do it that often, maybe once every month or so but everything I see is for syncing Google contacts.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, you might consider accepting some answers as correct. You've asked 27 questions and only accepted answers for 29 percent. Accepting answers is a way to say thank you to people answering. Not accepting answers is considered rude and wil decreas chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTC Sync](http://www.htc.com/www/howto.aspx?p_id=283&id=198&f=t), this will sync his calendar and contacts both ways.

Here's how:

> ### Setting Up Synchronization
>
> You can set up HTC Sync to synchronize
>   your computer's Outlook contacts and
>   calendar events with your phone. If
>   you're using Outlook Express on your
>   computer, you can only sync contacts
>   with your phone.
>
> Before you begin setting up
>   synchronization, make sure you have
>   set up HTC Sync to recognize your
>   phone. If you have not yet done so,
>   follow the steps in this topic:
>   [Setting Up HTC Sync to Recognize Your
>   Phone.](http://www.htc.com/www/howto.aspx?p_id=283&id=198&page=8)
>
> [image]
>
> HTC Sync's guided wizard lets you
>   easily set up synchronization in just
>   a few steps.
>
> On your computer, check and make sure
>   that the HTC Sync icon at the
>   bottom-right side of the screen
>   appears in green which means that your
>   phone is connected and HTC Sync
>   recognizes your phone.
>
> - If HTC Sync is not open, double-click the HTC Sync icon to open
>     it.
> - If you have just installed (or reinstalled) HTC Sync, click
>     Synchronize Now to start setting up
>     synchronization. (You can also click
>     Sync Manager > Settings.)
> - You will then see the Synchronization Settings Wizard dialog
>     box. Click Next.
> - Choose whether to sync your computer's Outlook or Outlook Express
>     with your phone, and then click Next.
>
> [image]
>
> - Select the type of information you want to sync (Contacts and/or
>     Calendar), and then click Next.
>
> [image]
>
> - Choose whether to sync manually or automatically with your phone, and
>     then click Next.
>
> [image]
>
> Important:  If you select I want to
>   sync automatically each time I connect
>   to my mobile phone, make sure you also
>   select the USB debugging option on
>   your phone so that your phone and
>   computer will automatically sync
>   whenever you connect them. On your
>   phone, press HOME > MENU, tap Settings
>
> > Applications > Development, and then select the USB debugging check box.
>
> - On the subsequent screen, view the choices you have made, and then click
>     Finish to confirm your choices. (If
>     you want to change something, you can
>     click Back until you get to the dialog
>     box where you want to make changes.)
>
> [image]
>
> HTC Sync then starts to sync your
>   phone and your computer. Wait for the
>   synchronization to finish.
>
> [image]
>
> - A summary report is then displayed. Click Close.

Answer (score 1):

HTC Android phones can store contact entries as **phone** entries or **Google** entries.
HTC Sync syncs Outlook contacts with **phone** entries on your phone.  These appear when you open **People** and **phone** is checked under menu->view.
Unfortunately, **phone** entries never sync with Gmail.
HTC Sync is fine for people who don't want to maintain Google contacts.  What's needed is a contact sync feature along the lines of Google Calendar Sync.

Answer (score 0):

there is a free software app called Google Calendar Sync
Download it and set it up to sync with your bosses Outlook profile and his Google account
You can set it so both of them sync, or desktop over writes google, or google over writes desktop

Then your phone syncs with google account and all is in synch :)

-EDIT-

Sorry I just realized you want contacts as well
In that case there is software called MailShadow which does exactly what you want
URL: http://www.cemaphore.com/mailshadow.php